# Get Git BranchName in WixSetup Project Build Variable

Tags: git, variables, msbuild, environment-variables, gitlab

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with GitLab. How can i get my current Git Branch Name in my VS Setup Projects Build Variable so that i can pass it to Wix's wxs file.

Something like this,
[image]

I tried few but did not work,
ProductName=$(Build.DefinitionName)
ProductName=$Env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME

Comment: Not sure if that is readily available as a variable but if you search around for e.g. 'msbuild git sha' you'll find solutions showing how to get the commit sha, usually by running msbuild'd Exec task with a git command and setting the output to a property which can then be used at will. the principle for getting the branch name is the same.

Comment: I assume from your question that you're trying to find the Gitlab CI Environment Variable that you could use to inject into your project. I would suggest that instead of doing that, you manually query it from Git, so that developer workstation builds (say build.cmd) could work too.

Comment: You can get this within CI from `CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` which contains `master` or `/your/complex/branch/name/here` or whatever.  http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: since Nov. 2016, GitLab has evolved, and some of its [variables have been renamed post GitLab 9.x/10.x](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/variables/README.html#9-0-renaming)

`CI_BUILD_REF_NAME` is now (2018) `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, and is the branch or tag name for which project is built.